# Finding Nth Minimum of a Varchar value in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table with the columns Config_ID, Escalation_Level

In this table the Escalation_Level is a **Varchar** with the values *'L0','L1','L2','L13','L4','L3','L5','L22','L19','L41''L98','L99*' in jumbled order for a Config_ID.

How to find the Nth MIN of the Escalation_Level. As this is of Varchar type, I don't find a straight forward way.

Please share your thoughts.

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: Does escalation_level contain 1 of the shown values or does it contain a comma separated list of values?

Comment: Hi Rene, the Escalation_Level contains all the above values as rows. They are NOT comma separated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the Nth value of anything then the analytic function [`NTH_VALUE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions114.htm#sthref1296) is a good place to start.

Assuming you want this based on the numeric part only you have to replace everything that is not a number, for which you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#sthref1426)

```
select regexp_replace(escalation_level, '[^[:digit:]]')
  from my_table
```

To obtain the Nth value for a given CONFIG_ID it would be:

```
select nth_value(escalation_level, n)
         over ( partition by config_id 
                    order by regexp_replace(escalation_level, '[^[:digit:]]') )
  from my_table
```

where `n` is the index of the value you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, you should use

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Config_ID ORDER BY Escalation_Level)
```

in this way you will be able to make Oracle to give you the Nth position of each Escalation_Level. When you should apply a filter.

Anyway check the [RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) and the [DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm#i1064409) analytic functions in the Oracle documentation